# How to add multiple set of data in Firebase android without overwriting them

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to Firebase, I am trying to create an inventory system. I am trying to add items to the inventory. Once the button to submit has been clicked it will call this function. I want multiple items to be saved but what happens here is that it keeps overwriting the existing items. I want my database to look something like the product in below image 
[image: this image here] 
but I don't want the title to be unique I want the title to be the serial number.

```
 private void writeNewItem(String ProductName, String SerialNo, String Quantity, String SupplierName, String SupplierPhone, String SupplierMail) {
    mDatabase.child("Product Name").setValue(ProductName);
    mDatabase.child("Serial No").setValue(SerialNo);
    mDatabase.child("Quantity").setValue(Quantity);
    mDatabase.child("Supplier Name").setValue(SupplierName);
    mDatabase.child("Supplier Phone").setValue(SupplierPhone);
    mDatabase.child("Supplier Mail").setValue(SupplierMail);
}
```

Comment: Yes, you are overwriting everything every time.  Please edit your question to describe what your database should look like after all this is done.  It looks like you really just want to pass a single Map object to `push()` rather than doing lots of different `setValue()`.

Comment: @DougStevenson push() will give me unique string which I dont want so is there any other way to solve this ?

Comment: Without a description or some picture of what you want your database to look like after your work is done, I don't think there's anything anyone can do to help.  Typically you use push() to add new information to a list-type structure in your database.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data

Comment: @DougStevenson I have edited my question and there is an image link to the word "this image here", sorry for the inconvenience caused.

Comment: All those nodes that start with "-KYZ" are all unique ids generated by push().  What you will need to do here is exactly what I mentioned before - pass a Map to push() to create a new child in the database that contains the fields and values in the map.  The docs I linked to show how to do that.  See the documentation here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#updating_or_deleting_data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply modify your function above to:

```
private void writeNewItem(String ProductName, String SerialNo, String Quantity,String SupplierName, String SupplierPhone, String SupplierMail) {
    DatabaseReference newProductRef = mDatabase.push();
    newProductRef.child("Product Name").setValue(ProductName);
    newProductRef.child("Serial No").setValue(SerialNo);
    newProductRef.child("Quantity").setValue(Quantity);
    newProductRef.child("Supplier Name").setValue(SupplierName);
    newProductRef.child("Supplier Phone").setValue(SupplierPhone);
    newProductRef.child("Supplier Mail").setValue(SupplierMail);
}
```

Hope this helps.